# Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation

Tags: .net, overriding, message, delphi-prism

I am trying to override "wndProc" method for my winform. So, that I can implement my own wndproc method for specific messages. I am able to successfully do that. However, now I am running into another issue which I have never seen before.

After successfully compiling it, I ran the program and it popped up with the following error message, "Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead."

My Overridden method winproc under protected access specifier:

```
method WndProc(var m:Message); override;
```

My definition of the method winproc as follows:

```
method MainForm.WndProc(var m: Message);
const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 161;
const WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274;
const HTCAPTION = 2;
const SC_MOVE = 61456;
begin
    if ((m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) and (m.WParam.ToInt32 = SC_MOVE)) then
    begin
        exit;
    end;

    if ((m.Msg = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN) and (m.WParam.ToInt32 = HTCAPTION)) then
    begin
        exit;
    end;
end;
```

**The Error is raised is in the program.pas file:**

```
[STAThread]
class method Program.Main(args: array of string);
begin
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.ThreadException += OnThreadException;
  using lMainForm := new MainForm do
    Application.Run(lMainForm); < --------Raised here.
end;
```

How do I go about resolving it?

Comment: Hmm, that should generate another exception, "Error creating window handle".  You must call the base method in your override.  Post the stack trace of the exception if that doesn't help.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. I also saw Error creating window handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by HansPassant, I included the base class wndproc and it works.

In Delphi-Prism, we do this.

inherited WndProc(var m);

same as base.wndproc(m);

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override the WndProc, and you don't really want to do so, because of the issue you ran into.  All you need to do is create a procedure that handles the specific message you want it to handle, and pass declare it as a message handler like this:

`procedure HandleSysCommand(var Msg: TWMSysCommand) ; message WM_SYSCOMMAND;`

The "Message WM_SYSCOMMAND" is what is telling your application what windows message you're handling, and you can use this to trap any standard or custom message.  For more, and more advanced information, it's pretty easy to do a seach for "Delphi Handle Windows Messages" to get back everything you'd need to take care of all your messaging needs.